# Difference between friction force and force because of friction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, work, friction

I'm doing some physics studying right now and the wording of an example question really confused me so I was hoping to get help in figuring it out. It says that " The coefficient of friction between the surface and the block is 0.11 and the force because of friction on the block is 15N." However the mass of the block is 20kg which when calculated to find the friction force is not the same as I end up getting 21.582N. I was wondering if there was a distinction between the two terms in the question or if I was doing something incorrectly as it is making it very difficult to try and find the work due to friction.

Answer (score 1):

according to me the coefficient of friction is 0.11 and mass of body is 20kg, so the max friction force or limiting friction will be μN which in this case if the surface is flat is μmg which will be 22N. So the maximum force exerted by friction opposing motion is 22N but lets assume if we put a force of 10N on the block then the friction force will be 10N as well (friction is a self adjusting force) and to make the block move the force we apply should be more than the limiting friction( in this case 22N). Hope this clears your doubts

Comment: Thank you very much, I looked my question over and realized I had forgotten to take the fact that the block was on an incline into account, and after doing so I see that the force is indeed 15N. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: Im glad i was able to solve your doubt :)